# What is the difference between Sender and From in EWS?

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

The `Mailbox` element has child elements named `Sender` and `From`. And I'm really confused about the difference between them.

This is what the documentation says about `Sender`:

> The Sender element specifies the e-mail address of the person who sent an item

And about `From`:

> The From element represents the address from which the message was sent

Really, it doesn't make any difference for me. The XML that I see is always the same for the both elements. So what is the real difference between these two?

Comment: Check https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4021#section-2.1.2[link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4021#section-2.1.2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but I still don't understand what the actual difference is. Can you please explain it in a plain language?

Comment: The difference is subtle. Sender and From are redundant in most cases. More explanation can be read here [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822) paragraph 4.4. Bottomline: Just From is OK. But I can imagine some mailers require both fields to be defined

Comment: If you can imagine such a case could you please describe it as simply as possible as an answer to my question. I will accept and upvote your answer and you will get 25 points)))

Comment: Sorry, I can not make it clearer then the RFC, I referenced before, does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain English:

`From` is who the message is from. It is who the recipient's email client should display the message is from.

`Sender` is usually the same as `From`, **unless** the message was originated by somebody, or some other system than the actual `From` address.

Example: Gmail when it's configured for a domain not hosted by Gmail. The `From` would contain you@yourdomain.com, but the `Sender` will contain someone@gmail.com. Many mail clients will render this as someone@gmail.com on behalf of you@yourdomain.com.

From Official RFC -  [Registration of Mail and MIME Header Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.2)

> ```
> 2.1.2. Header Field: From
>
> Description:  
>     Mailbox of message author  
> [...]  
> Related information:
>     Specifies the author(s) of the message; that is, the mailbox(es)
>     of the person(s) or system(s) responsible for the writing of the
>     message. Defined as standard by RFC 822.
>
> 2.1.3. Header Field: Sender
>
> Description:  
>     Mailbox of message sender  
> [...]  
> Related information:
>     Specifies the mailbox of the agent responsible for the actual
>     transmission of the message.  Defined as standard by RFC 822.
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'm extremely sorry for asking dumb questions, but how can it be that " the message was originated by somebody, or some other system than the actual From address"? I cannot imagine that. Can you please describe a real world scenario when this might happen?

Comment: No problem. I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: Another example one user sending on behalf of another user - e.g. a secretary sending on behalf of an executive.